# Sending complex object in ajax to MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

The value of `List<Order>` returns as `null` in my controller action method while sending the complex object. Can someone help to identify the issue? Do we need to pass array of objects with indexes?

### JavaScript

```
function OnCustomerClick() {
    //var orders = [];
    //orders.push({ 'OrderId': '1', 'OrderBy': 'Saroj' });

    var complexObject = {
        FirstName: 'Saroj',
        LastName: 'K',
        //Orders : orders
        Orders: [{ OrderId: 1, OrderBy: 'Saroj' }, { OrderId: 2, OrderBy: 'Kumar' }]
    };

    var obj = { customer: complexObject };
    var data2send = JSON.stringify(obj);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Home/TestCustomer1',
        data: data2send,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (arg) { //call successfull
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            //error occurred
        }
    });
};
```

### MVC

```
 public ActionResult TestCustomer1(Customer customer)
    {
        return Json(customer);
    }
```

### C#

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    List<order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string  OrderBy { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can try adding the `traditional: true,` ajax option, but really it should be `var complexObject = { FirstName: 'Saroj', LastName: 'K', Orders[0].OrderId: 1, Orders[0].OrderBy: 'Saroj', Orders[1].OrderId: 2, Orders[1].OrderBy: 'Kumar' }` to correctly bind to your model (and delete `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` and just use `data: complexObject,`

Comment: @user3559349 This comment saved me with a similar situation—putting all the data for the List<> type property into the same object as the rest of the properties but with array notation. I was trying to nest the objects which didn't work at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use *public* properties for model binding. `Orders` currently has no access modifier, so its private.

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<order> Orders { get; set; } // <----
}
```

Other than that, everything looks fine.